# xml file drill down

Tags: xml

For starters is my xml file set up correctly? I am new to using xml data.
I've set my file up accordingly. I want to be able to pull all the county names into a dropdownlist based on the statename parameter i send the function.

Here is an xml sample, the real file has every state it in structured in this manner

```
<data>
<states>
 <state>
  <name>Delaware</name>
  <counties>
    <county>Kent County</county>
    <county>New Castle County</county>
    <county>Sussex County</county>
  </counties>
</state>
</states>
</data>
```

I can get to the state level but not sure how to extract the counties based on the statename.

```
Public Shared Function CountiesfromState(statename As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()

    'Load XML from the file into XmlDocument object
    doc.Load("StateCounties.xml") 'this needs    
    Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement

    'Select all nodes with the statename indicated by the nodestring variable
    Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("states/state")
    For Each elem As XmlElement In nodeList

    Next
    Return (From node As XmlNode In nodeList Select node.InnerText).ToList()
End Function
```

Comment: Please add to the question what you've tried...especially where you mention that you "can get to the state level"

Comment: Original post now edited

Comment: The only thing I would add to your XML is this at the top: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, you probably don't need `<data>` as a wrapper around the whole thing, it could just be `<states>`, but whatever is necessary for your application.  As far as the programming language goes, is that Classic ASP or ASP.Net?  I haven't used either in a while, but it wasn't one of your tags in the post, so I'm not sure.

Comment: it is .Net, the meta tag is in the xml at the top already